# Операции над массивом

Tags: массивы

В одномерном массиве, состоящем из вещественных элементов, вычислить:

- Б) сумму элементов массива, расположенных между максимальным и минимальным элементами.
- В) произведение элементов, значения которых не вошли в интервал. Значения задавать с клавиатуры.
- Г) отсортировать массив методом вставки.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Находим индексы максимального и минимального значения (положим, imin и imax). Это очень просто. Далее суммируем значения элементов от imin+1 до imax-1.
2. Считаем произведение элементов с индексами от 0 до imin-1 и от imax+1 до конца.
3. В интернете полно материалов. Учимся пользоваться гуглем.

Comment: боюсь, ваш ответ автору не поможет - в силу незнания (вероятно, полного) основ программирования, ей нужно готовое решение

Comment: за готовым решением надо обратиться к однокласснику, накормив его конфетами и чмокнув в носик.

Comment: не помогло. пробовала и конфетами и всем подобным :(

Comment: @MARINOKA: бросайте этого одноклассника, найдите на год старше. (Лучше отличника.)

Comment: найдите себе мужика с машиной, деньгами и квартирой. И бросайте это программирование

Comment: не нужен мне мужик. хочу сама всего добиться

Comment: Вам не нужен мужик с деньгами, машиной и квартирой? Давайте познакомимся? Я буду лучше одноклассника (даже отличника)

Comment: давайте :)

Comment: Вот так и нашли друг друга два одиночества...

Comment: @mikillskegg: (по делу) надо бы сказать, что `imin` -- минимум из индекса макс. и мин. элемента. Сейчас можно подумать, что это индекс мин. элемента. Ещё стоит подумать, что делать в случае если мин./макс. элементов несколько.

Comment: крайних случаев будет несколько:

- элементов в массиве - 1
- как уже сказали несколько минимальных и максимальных
- если все элементы равны

@mikillskegg, если индекс максимального меньше индекса минимального, как производить подсчёты?

Comment: А вот пусть тов. спрашивающая об этом и подумает.

Comment: @Spectre, вот от случая все элементы равны и надо начинать. Остальные сводятся к нему. 

Что делать если... Очевидно найти максимум из 4-х расстояний между комбинациями из крайних (по индексам) минимальных и крайних максимальных. Вот его концы и разделят массив на 3 части.

--

Зря @ХэшКод закрыл вопрос. Реально он оказался не так прост для начинающих. 

Может @MARINOKA интуитивно чувствует эту глубину и боится даже начинать?

Comment: ну я не могу даже понять,как подойти к этим задачам

Comment: @MARINOKA, для начала введите массив с клавиатуры, найдите в нем (по одному, для начала) минимальный и максимальный элементы и напечатайте их индексы.

Для начала в олном цикле минимум, а в другом максимум. Через несколько минут (уверен) Вам понадобится уже один цикл для их поиска.

Потом легче пойдет. Т.е. если всю задачу (надеюсь, пока) обдумать не получается, то выделяйте из нее осмысленный кусочек и программируйте его.

Затем добавите что-нибудь еще, потом третье, и поехали...

Comment: моё решение на js: [https://gist.github.com/4155038](https://gist.github.com/4155038)

Comment: @Spectre, красиво!